# Cannot download file from S3 using DownloadManager

Tags: android, amazon-s3, android-download-manager, download-manager, pre-signed-url

Is there a way to download a file from S3 using Android DownloadManager?
When i tried downloading using retrofit, i had to verify hostname, for the url to work. Using DownloadManager, how can i achieve this?

The url looks like this.

```
https://bucket-name.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/app/apk/22/app.apk?AWSAccessKeyId=""&Expires=""&Signature=""
```

Comment: You can simply use an intent for this

Comment: @gcantoni Sorry, i don't understand. What kind of intent?